# what is the optimized way to write query

Tags: mysql

I have below query which I want to optimized

```
SELECT  -- COUNT(message_queue_id_pk)
message_queue_id_pk, q.media_filename_original, a.media_filename_original, 
processed_flag , schedule_flag, q.message_mode, q.added_datetime
FROM messages_queue q
LEFT JOIN messages_all a ON q.media_filename_original = 
a.media_filename_original
WHERE q.message_type_flag != 1 AND a.media_filename_original IS NULL AND 
processed_flag = 2
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Read up on [Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: Can you provide some more information? How many rows do you have? What indexes you have set? Output of `explain`? Current query execution time?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please edit your question to summarize what you learned from browsing among the trillion MySQL SO questions re "optimize", "performance", "best" etc & from reading about SQL query optimization generally. Google my comments that look like this comment. Read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You should not use column related  to left joined  table in where condition .. in this way you have an inner join so  .. 
first buil the right query  moving the a.media_filename_original IS NULL  in the ON condition

Assuming processed_flag and schedule_flag are in q table

```
  SELECT  -- COUNT(message_queue_id_pk)
    message_queue_id_pk
    , q.media_filename_original
    , a.media_filename_original
    , processed_flag 
    , schedule_flag
    , q.message_mode
    , q.added_datetime
  FROM messages_queue q
  LEFT JOIN messages_all a ON q.media_filename_original = a.media_filename_original 
            AND a.media_filename_original IS NULL
  WHERE q.message_type_flag != 1 
  processed_flag = 2
  LIMIT 10;
```